# How to place two Tspan on top of each other

Tags: html, svg

I have the below code:

```
<svg width="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1500 2500" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text width="40" x="40" y="250" font-size="350">3</text>
  <text width="60" x="470" y="340" font-size="340" text-anchor="start">
    <tspan>YEARS</tspan>
    <tspan>YEARS</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

I want the two tspans to be on top of each other instead of next to each other. How would I go about doing this? One solution was to have another text element under it but I feel it would be neater to have them in the spans.

Also I'm new to coding SVG so if there is anything that you see and think should be changed please let me know.

Comment: By the doc of ``tspan`` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan), every ``tspan`` element can have ``x`` and ``y`` attributes. If they match, they will be on top of each other. I have no idea if there is a better way than absolute coordinates. Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/h53b41Ln/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added  x="0" dy="1.2em" in tspan

```
  <svg width="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1500 2500" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text width="40" x="40" y="250" font-size="350">3</text>
  <text width="60" x="470" y="340" font-size="340" text-anchor="start">
    <tspan >YEARS</tspan>

    <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">YEARS</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: What does DY stand for?

Comment: The dy attribute indicates a shift along the y-axis on the position of an element or its content. What exactly is shifted depends on the element for which this attribute is set.  Please see http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/tspan-element.html  section "Vertical Positioning"